# How to compile my C++ library in pure Android Studio way (without specifying any .mk file on our own)

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, openssl, java-native-interface

At the beginning, I have to say I already searched around as many possible answers as I can to my answer. Some of them are really helpful, but not in Android Studio way. Also, I can get my JNI worked with the well-known example "**getStringFromNative()**", so please don't give me this kind of links. What I have tried so far :

**1. structure of my directory**

```
app 
 |- src
     |- main
         |- java
         |- jni
             |- libs
                 |- libcrypto.a
                 |- libssl.a
             |- openssl
                 |- xxxxx.h
                 |...... -> those .h file of openssl
             |- com_ais_ndksample_MainActivity.h
             |- CipherModule.cpp
             |- CipherModule.h
```

**2. build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ais.ndksample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {

            moduleName "JniDemo"

        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {

          jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni']

          jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/libs']

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

}
```

3. The errors occurred in my CipherModule.cpp, I have several  statement on the top as below:

   ```
   #include "CipherModule.h"
   #include <openssl/aes.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <iostream>
   ```

and the #include  shows warning that **Unused import statement**, but I did use that. When I built, I got the error message indicated as followed:

```
undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key`
undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt`
```

As a result, I doubted that I didn't make my openssl library right, but I did specify it in my build.gradle. I had made so much efforts on this and got no luck. Any clue or thought would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: I am not aware that there is support for depending upon static libraries as you are here. There definitely is no such support in the [upcoming Gradle plugin overhaul](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental). Even if depending upon static libraries is supported, I would expect them to have to be organized by ABI -- your directory structure does not indicate the CPU architecture for those `.a` files.

Comment: [This guy claims to have gotten static library support working](http://blog.marcingil.com/android-ndk-link-static-library-to-your-jni-library/), but that was 18 months ago and required a makefile.

Comment: Thanks for your information! I will check out the link you provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the root cause of this. The error messages I got as below:

```
undefined reference to `AES_set_encrypt_key`
undefined reference to `AES_cbc_encrypt`
```

are due to the fact that my libcrypto.a and libssl.a library are not built for android-armv7 based devices. I solved this issue by "cross-compile" my openssl for armv7. The script is shown as follow:

```
export CC=/your_path_to_sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

export AR=/your_path_to_sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar

export RANLIB=/your_path_to_sdk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-ranlib

./Configure android-armv7

export ANDROID_DEV=/your_path_to_sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/usr

make
```

You can run this script inside your openssl folder downloaded from [official website](https://www.openssl.org/) and your will get your libcrypto.a and libssl.a inside openssl folder. Those are compiled for android this time. If you guys still encounter similar issues, feel free to ask me!

Comment: Hello @pptang. I have this problem. I want add OpenSSl into Android Studio. I just use cpp support by android studio. But, I don't know how to add openssl into android studio when use cpp. Can you help me?